# Prevent scp and less commands reading interactive tcsh script

Tags: shell, scp, less, tcsh, interactive

I'm using tsch through PuTTY, and let's start by this: please don't try to convince me to migrate to another shell...:)

It's being a long time that commands like `scp` and `less` didn't work well for me. After searching I found out, as many others, that this was because of echo commands that interrupt `scp` and `less`.
I found out that moving those 'echoing commands' to the .login file instead of .cshrc or .self_schrc solved the problem.

However, there's one issue: I want to change title of the PuTTY window according to the directory I'm currently in. I managed to do so by aliasing `setprompt printf "\033]0"` and execute `setpropmt`. But then again - this `printf` ruins my `scp` and `less`. And this time - I can't move the execution of `setprompt` into .login, for certain reason.

Now, I read here and there that you can leave those 'echo commands' in the .cshrc files if you're checking for interactive shell, since `less` and `scp` won't execute lines of interactive shell.

I tried few methods, such as:

```
if { tty -s } then
```

or

```
if ($?prompt) then
```

but it seems that `less` is still 'reading' those line, and hence - giving me wrong output.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you move your `\033]0` into `$prompt` instead?

Comment: OK, I just did it, and it solved this particular problem indeed. But still - I want to know what's wrong with the previous code, just in case I encounter something I can't solve like this.

Comment: At what point, while you're running `less`, do you see the stray output from `setprompt`?

Comment: I don't understand why this affects `less` in the first place. it doesn't run a shell, so why would your shell prompt have any effect on it?

Comment: @Barmar - have a look over here: http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html#profileout `less` DOES run a shell...